# OpenCV Best method to automatically draw a straight line through points

Tags: python, opencv, draw

what OpenCV Python tool would be the best to draw a straight line between multiple *'points'* on an image ?
Something like a BestFitLine but for thresoldedimage, not a plot

Thanks

source image
[image]

processed image (binary threshold)
the black dot are supposed to be each individual crop
[image: source image (binary threshold]

what I'd like to have

[image]

Comment: Could you please post the input image before thresholding?

Comment: I added the source RGB image

Comment: You could try creating a diagonal shaped kernel then performing morph close. `kernel = np.eye(25, k=0, dtype=np.uint8)[::-1]` then 
 `close = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=5)`. This will connect the lines then you can use your favorite line detector

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid Hough Lines will fail here. You could try `ransac` to get best estimated line, erase those points and run next `ransac`. Tough you still can encounter some troubles: exactly how many clusters do you want to recognize? You could set min score sample score for a line model. You'd also need to filter out horizontal lines.

There're `ransac` implementations in both [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ransac.html) and [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/transform/plot_ransac.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't tried yet, go with the OpenCV functions `HoughLines()` and `HoughLinesP()` to detect lines in an image.